# get dropdown information out and go in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It is such that I have a drop down and I some information that I should throw into the database,

Right now gives me this one error:

> The name 'ddlRoles' does not exist in the current context

**My code:** - brugere.fk_role is what I need to get "going" to the database.

**KontoController.cs**

```
brugere.Fk_role = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoles);
```

**Opret.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlRoles",
new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name"), "Vælg",
new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })
```

How can it be that it will take "my" value into kontocontroller.cs

It is such that I must have the value from the drop down into the database so I will only have spoken out and looked over / into the database.

**EIDT UPDATE!**

**Kontocontroller.cs**

```
// GET: Konto/Opretbruger
    public ActionResult Opret()
    {

        Opret newopret = new Opret();
        newopret.User = new User();
        newopret.Sexs = db.Sexes.ToList();//henter de to "køn"
        newopret.Roles = db.Roles.Where(z => z.id >= 6).ToList();//Tag to alle "ranks" efter id 6 eller =
        newopret.Professionals = db.Professionals.ToList(); //Hvilke slags hjælp kan man få
        newopret.Areas = db.Areas.ToList();//hvilke område kommer man fra

        return View(newopret);//viser indhold frem på siden.
    }


    //opret brugere i databasen i user tablen. Det er de oplysning database skal have ind i første om gang.
    //Det vil sige at den skal lige det ind i databasen
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUsers(OpretBrugere brugere)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Tjekker op på om der findes en brugere med den email.
            var CreateAnAccount = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == brugere.Email);
            if(CreateAnAccount != null)
            {

                brugere.Email = hello; //<--- Information fra textbox here
                brugere.PasswordHash = hello; //<--- Information fra textbox here
                brugere.FirstName = hello; //<--- Information fra textbox here
                brugere.LastName = hello; //<--- Information fra textbox here

                //true - False
                brugere.Newsletter = hello;  //<--- Information fra checkbox here

                brugere.Fk_role = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoles); //Det er her problemet e rb
                brugere.Fk_sex = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSexs);
                brugere.Fk_area = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAreas);
                brugere.Fk_professional = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProfessionals);

                //age
                brugere.age = hello;  //<--- Information fra textbox her

                //img users
                brugere.img = "userimg.png";

                brugere.creatadate = DateTime.Now;

                //Skal finde ud af hvilke role man har valgt,
                if(brugere.Fk_role == 6)
                {
                    //Hvis man er Mentor, skal man ikke have adgang til siden endnu!
                    brugere.Approved = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Er man Alm brugere eller Forældre så har man adgang til site.
                    brugere.Approved = true;
                }

                //skal lige indhold ind i databasen.
                db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(brugere); 

                //skal gemme indholdet.
                db.SubmitChanges(); // save

                //sende person til log in siden.

            }
            else
            {
                //Fremviser en fejl besked hvis der findes en email.
                ViewBag.MessageError = "Denne brugere findes i vores system.";
            }
        }
        //return indhold til siden.
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Show more of your controller - do you have a `ddlRoles` being passed into the action (either directly, or by way of a view model)?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Where I pull out the list are in the same error when I create users to the database.

Comment: Yes, but you need to show the whole controller code if you want to get your question answered

Comment: @BrendanGreen i have update its now, ;) I add all the code I've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdown box is being created with an Id / Name that does not existing in your model (`OpretBrugere`).  `ddlRoles` isn't even defined anywhere (that you've shown), so that code won't even compile.

You probably want to add a "selected role" property to your model, and bind the drop down to it so that it is sent with the post data.

Add to `OpretBrugere`:

```
public string SelectedRole { get; set; }
```

Then change the rendering of the drop down in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRole, 
    new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name"), "Vælg",
    new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })
```

Then in your post action:

```
brugere.Fk_role = Convert.ToInt32(brugere.SelectedRole);
```

Comment: No where is it nice that you could just help me with it. and it works now !! .. damn nice and I also hope you will give me a +1 for questions.